# Puppet Use of 'hiera.yaml' version 3 is deprecated. It should be converted to version 5

Tags: puppet

In Centos 7 with Puppet v4.9.2, trying to install java and tomcat. When i run the apply command. it giving the warning message.

Any help to resolvethis warning message?

```
node 'webserver' {          
        class { 'java' :
                distribution  => 'jdk',
                package       => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
        }

        tomcat::install { '/opt/tomcat9':
                source_url => 'http://apache.osuosl.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M17/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17.tar.gz',
        }
        tomcat::instance { 'tomcat9-1':
                catalina_home => '/opt/tomcat9',
                 catalina_base => '/opt/tomcat9/1',
        }
}
```

Message

```
Warning: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml: Use of 'hiera.yaml' version 3 is deprecated. It should be converted to version 5
   (in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml)
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function, with Pattern[]. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/java/manifests/init.pp", 54]:
   (at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:25:in `deprecation')
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function, with Stdlib::Compat::Bool. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/tomcat/manifests/init.pp", 40]:["/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/tomcat/manifests/install.pp", 20]
   (at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:25:in `deprecation')
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function, with Stdlib::Compat::Absolute_Path. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp", 70]:
   (at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:25:in `deprecation')
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function, with Stdlib::Compat::String. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp", 71]:
   (at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:25:in `deprecation')
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use match expressions with Stdlib::Compat::String instead. They are described at https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_data_type.html#match-expressions. at ["/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp", 72]:
   (at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:25:in `deprecation')
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use match expressions with Stdlib::Compat::Bool instead. They are described at https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_data_type.html#match-expressions. at ["/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp", 82]:
   (at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:25:in `deprecation')
Notice: Compiled catalog for webserver in environment production in 0.66 seconds
```

Thanks
Sr

Comment: Which version of the tomcat/stdlib module are you using?

Comment: @Frap Here is the version I have.  "name": "puppetlabs-tomcat",
  "version": "1.6.1",
"name": "puppetlabs-stdlib",
  "version": "4.15.0",

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/hiera_intro.html#whats-the-deal-with-hiera-5

Comment: This hiera file came with rpm pacakge. do I need to replace this file with different version?     rpm -qf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
puppet-agent-1.9.2-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: installed lastest rpm from puppet lab rpm site. name=Puppet Labs PC1 Repository el 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/PC1/$basearch

Comment: Ok then basically yes: convert your hiera config to version 5. Also maybe raise an issue with Puppet on their JIRA that they are packaging hiera 3 configs with their AIO and then throwing a deprecation warning for it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I looked at puppet github hiear  latest tag version is 3.3.0 https://github.com/puppetlabs/hiera. How can I conver hiear config to version 5?

Comment: Use the link I posted above. Also, Hiera version 5 (and 4) is part of the Puppet Data Provider and part of the source code within Puppet itself. Hiera will cease to be a separate product very soon. This is also explained in the link I gave you above.

Answer (score 4):

As Matt pointed out I need to conver my yaml file to version 5.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/hiera_config_yaml_5.html

I have updated like below. now I don't get this warnning.

```
version: 5
hierarchy:
  - name: Common
    path: common.yaml
defaults:
  data_hash: yaml_data
  datadir: data
```

thanks for the help.
Sr

Answer (score -1):

Using any of the installation steps from [here](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/hiera) worked for me with direct manual installation

```
puppet module install puppet-hiera --version 5.0.1
```